# Creating a module which handle other modules

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I just got involved in Orchard, so I apologize for any confusing terms.
from what I learned and read you can pretty much customize Orchard to include or exclude anything you want since its a framework in the first place, so features like MVC, modules are really parts of the framework but not it's not essentially based on.

> is it possible to create a module which interacts with other modules?

To make it clear, say we have a module which does something like an API call, fetching data and displaying it to the user **Only**. 
how can I create a module that will control this module behavior (when, why)?
what is meant by **When, Why**   this module will only control **when** this module should be executed and if not **why **.

this can be implemented on the module itself, but say we have a lot of module with pretty much the same thing .to follow the DRY we will certainly need to separate controlling this module in a separate module.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: its like building an httpmodule which will catch all requests then decide which one pass through .

Comment: Please state a simple example of the *when, why* thing. I think the question is currently too broad for answering it correctly.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Example i want to use the Tokenization Pattern on authentication and services . the module i want to create will get the current Token of the Authenticated user and call an external API to determine if the permission is garanted.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy To clarify more , what i learned , the modules will be called only if if its accessible via a controller , what i want is a module which will interact with a behavior of other modules . (Eg. Authentication is already included but i want my module to be called each time a user sign in  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [post](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7949#issuecomment-359738907) on GitHub you can implement [`IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard/Security/IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler.cs) and in that implementation you can call your external API to check for a specific permission.

I've done this myself in the past to check for fine grained permissions that were configured / stored in a separate DB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! another little question is it possible to use Themed attribute outside controllers ?

Comment: Regarding the `Themed` attribute: please create a separate question for it. It's generally discouraged to discuss multiple questions at once.

Comment: thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400301/orchard-themed-attribute-outside-controllers