# Orchard Themed Attribute outside controllers

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have a service which will override the content of the response body.

is it possible to  use themed within the method which override the content ?

```
[Themed]
public void forbiddenAlert(IHttpContextAccessor Hca) 
{
  // overriding response body 
}
```

Comment: Is `forbiddenAlert` a controller action?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy No its a method called on the `Checking(CheckAccessContext context)` in `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler`  Eventhandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i don't think this will work as the `Themed` attribute is intended for decorating a controller only.

Also i don't think you follow the right approach for denying access. The event handler should not override the response body (seperation of concerns and it most likely won't work anyway). The `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler` should check permissions and return whether access is granted or not. What`s happening when a permission is granted or not granted is normally a concern of other code parts. I would go this route:

1. implement proper permission checks ([`IAuthorizer`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard/Security/Authorizer.cs), [`IAuthorizationService`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard/Security/IAuthorizationService.cs)) in all modules with a fallback on failure to whatever is suitable e.g. redirecting to a forbidden error page
2. add an `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler` to implement the checks accordingly