# C# OrchardCMS Enable features dynamically

Tags: c#, orchardcms

as a part of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424383/store-global-token-in-cache) . is there any way to Enable Features Dynamically ?

What I'm trying to achieve is the same exact concept of [Permissions](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Custom-permissions/) in Orchard . Except that instead of restricting the user from using this features, i don't want them to be displayed in the front-end.

this still can be achieved using custom permissions BUT the different which i mentioned in question which is answered by [ViRuSTriNiTy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392157/creating-a-module-which-handle-other-modules) , the permissions is not instantiated Immediately but it will be received from a third-part API on the `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler`

```
    public void Complete(CheckAccessContext context)
    {
     /// get the permission for the current IUser via thirdpart API
     /// Enable/Disable features depending on the response
    }
```

say i will be receiving a json response like this below :

```
[{ "Permission": "Home"  }, { "Permission": "Videos"  }]
```

Comment: Features are enables per tenant, very early. I don't think there's a way to enable or disable them per request or that late. Permissions seem to be the way to go for what you're trying to achieve. Asynchronicity shouldn't be an issue, especially with proper caching.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy permissions will restrict users without permissions to use them , but i want to disable the display not the functionality

Comment: No, permissions are just something you can check, and you can do so anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EnableFeatures()` / `DisableFeatures()` of the [IModuleService](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Modules/Services/IModuleService.cs) interface.

This might not work in handlers though, i never had a case where i needed to enable / disable a feature in a handler.

Comment: Wouldn't those calls enable/disable features for the whole tenant?

Comment: @Bovaz Yes of course, enabling / disabling always affects the tenant. Why do you ask?

Comment: I thought the question was about doing stuff per-user

Comment: @Bovaz Good catch. The linked question is refering to a specific user but this question does not mention "specific user" again. So i'm not really sure what the intention was :/